# As3: Bullet giving me errors?

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime-error, movieclip, addchild, projectile

I have an enemy class which spawns bullets at the player.

```
        private function fireBullet()
        {
            if(isFiring)
            {
            fire();
            }
        }

    public function fire():void
    {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(x, y, rotation);
        stage.addChild(bullet);
    }
```

And in the bullet class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip {

    private var _root:MovieClip;
    private var isVanished:Boolean = false;

    public function Bullet(x:int, y:int, rotation:Number) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rotation = rotation;

        _root = MovieClip(root);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }

    private function loop (event:Event):void
    {           
        if(this.hitTestObject(_root.assassin.hitbox))
               {
                   _root.hitPoints -= 30;
                               }


        else
        {
            y-=Math.cos(rotation/-180*Math.PI)*(15);
            x-=Math.sin(rotation/-180*Math.PI)*(15);
        }

        if(this.x < 0 || this.x > _root.stageWidth || this.y > _root.stageWidth || this.y < 0)
        {
            removeChild(this);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
    }
}

}
```

However, when I start the game, I get a 1009 error regarding line 23, and the game slows down rapidly as the bullets don't even move.

I also get an 1063 error, expecting 3 but having 0.

> ```
> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argumentblabla for Bullet(). Expected 3 but 0 were shown. ((translated))
> at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
> at flash.display::Sprite()
> at flash.display::MovieClip()
> at Main()[C:\Venture Inc\Main.as:189]
> ```

This is what main looks like

```
//Constructor
        public function Main()
        {

            addChild(container_staff);
            addChild(container_wall);

                  etc etc etc
```

Comment: I feel like we are missing some context. Could you post all the code?

Comment: There is a lot of code, so I don't really know what else to post..

I noticed, if I remove all code except (_root.hitPoints -= 30;), I still get the error.

It seems as if the error means _root. is null?

Comment: Well the best way to troubleshoot if you aren't sure where yo start is to add a few trace statements, see which ones get executed before the error, and the once you've found where the error might be start commenting out lines to see if you can get the error to go away. Once you find it fixing it should be easy.

Comment: As I said, if I only have 

private function loop (event:Event):void
    {           
         _root.hitPoints -= 30;
    }

It still gives me the error. It must be related to _root. (it's properly defined, though: private var _root:MovieClip; and then _root = MovieClip(root); in the constructor.

Comment: Sure it is, except I can't see where it's defined. All your code looks fine, assuming that the parts that aren't show are correct. Which apparently they aren't if you are getting an error? The error reads like you forgot to add some arguments when you called a method/constructor

Comment: Ok, just added all of the code for the bullet class

Answer (score 0):

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argumentblabla for Bullet(). Expected 3 but 0 were shown. ((translated))
```

Bullet class constructor has 3 arguments. Check your code more precisely, I think you have something like this:

```
var bullet: Bullet = new Bullet();
```

Also there is problem with your code. Every bullet subscribes for the ENTER_FRAME. Centralize your game, create main loop, and update all game actors(bullets, enemies, etc) from there.